# Why compiler execute OnShow event first and OnHide later in TTabSheet?

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol, ttabsheet

I'm using a `TPageControl` with 2 `TTabSheet` (ModifyTab and DeleteTab) and I have code in `OnShow` and `OnHide` events for both tabs . I was thinking that when I clicks anyone of these tabs, `OnHide` event of the selected Tab occurs first and clicked tab´s `OnShow` event later but it´s the opposite. Why's that?

I create a `TDictionary` in every `OnShow` event and free in every `OnHide` but compiler raises an exception because it executes `OnShow` event, then executes `OnHide` and then I can't use the Dictionary because it's `nil` and destroyed.

Comment: Sounds like the new TabSheet is shown before the previous TabSheet is hidden (I don't have access to Delphi right now to confirm in its source). Try using the `TPageControl`'s `OnChanging` and `OnChange` events instead. Are you using a single dictionary for both TabSheets, or does each TabSheet have its own dictionary? Please show your actual code you are having trouble with. The order of the `On(Show|Hide)` wouldn't be a problem if you were using separate dictionaries. You could use the `TTabSheet.Tag` to track with dictionary belongs to which TabSheet.

Comment: Just nitpicking: the compiler isn't executing anything, it is just making the executable out of your source code. Also, it isn't even responsible for this behaviour; instead, this happens because the VCL page control is designed this way.

Comment: The compiler isn't executing anything, that's a big true. I'm trying to create a dictionary for each tab and I think it's my solution. Thanks.

Comment: Let me se if I understand you correctly. You have one global TDictionary object whose contents should depend on which TTabSheet is being shown. But you are experiencing problem because when you are switching tabs the new tabs gets shown before old tabs gets hidden. Right? Well since the contents of TDictionary are dependent on each tab have you ever considered adding TDictionary object to each tab instead of using a global one. This would allow you to avoid any troubles of order in which your tabs are shown/hidden. In fact you would even get a chance to show multiple tabs at the same time

Comment: Why not use the OnChange and/or the OnChanging event of TPageControl instead. Then the order of Hide/Show is unimportant.